# Azure Kinect not connecting or showing up in device manager?

Tags: azure, kinect, azurekinect

I just got an Azure Kinect and tried connecting it, but it does not enumerate in device manager or Azure Kinect Viewer.  I have it plugged into USB 3.1 in a new Lenovo Y740 15", but the light is still blinking white on the Azure Kinect.  I also went through the steps to reset the device, but the light continued to just blink white.  Would anyone happen to have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the meaning of the indicators here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/Kinect-dk/hardware-specification

Flashing white means that the camera does not have a data connection to the host PC. You mention you are using USB 3.1 (assume USB-C connector). Is the cable you are using a power+data capable or just power. Some USB-C cables are power only.